# JNI :: How hbmcolor is calculated internally in c language

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am using WINDOWS 7 64-bit machine.JNI

I am using ICONINFO in my C code. Which store the icon information in it. 
With SetByteArrayRegion() method i had copyed the iconinfo information to a byte array of java. 
From this byte array i need to get hbmColor. 
The struture of ICONINFO is as follows _`ICONINFO { BOOL fIcon; DWORD xHotspot; DWORD yHotspot; HBITMAP hbmMask; HBITMAP hbmColor; }`

Although i can get the hbmcolor from ICONINFO easily in C code. **How i can do it in java.**
How hbmcolor is calculated internally in c language ?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) instead of raw JNI. Anyway, copying a struct into a byte array is not the right way to do interop. You should have your JNI code create a Java object of a type that has fields that correspond to the ones in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

In a 64 bits DLL, `hbmColor` is at offset 24, that is: the first byte is the 25th in the struct. `hbmColor` is 8 bytes long.

Method:

```
size_t offset = offsetof(struct _ICONINFO, hbmColor);
```

I don't know what you want to do in Java with the `hbmColor`. it's a Win32 `handle`. Perhaps better to follow millimoose's advice.